# KafkaConsumer disconnected on subscription

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using kafka-clients 3.6.1 (current latest version) to instantiate and subscribe to a topic on a remote broker (whose configurations I can't change).

While subscribing, the KafkaConsumer gets disconnected and retries to subscribe indefinitely.
I will add that I'm using PlainLoginModule in the properties for authentication.

Here's my simple implementation:

```java
public class KafkaProbeConsumer extends KafkaProbe {
  private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(KafkaProbeConsumer.class);
  private static final int POLLING_DELAY = 5000;
  private KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = null;

  public KafkaProbeConsumer(Properties props) throws Exception {
    super(props);
    logger.info("New KafkaProbeConsumer");
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    logger.info("Creating Kafka Consumer...");
    try {
      consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
      logger.info("Kafka Consumer created");

      consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(Constants.KAFKA_TOPIC));

      while (!closed.get()) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> messages = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(POLLING_DELAY));

        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> message : messages) {
          logger.info("Offset:{}, Key:{}, Value:{}", message.offset(), message.key(), message.value());
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error("Error during Kafka Consumer's job", ex);
    } finally {
      consumer.close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void shutdown() throws Exception {
    logger.info("Shutting down");
    consumer.close();
  }

}
```

```java
public abstract class KafkaProbe implements Runnable {
  public static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(KafkaProbe.class);
  public Properties props = null;
  public AtomicBoolean closed = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  public KafkaProbe(Properties p) throws Exception {
    props = p;
    
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          shutdown();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          logger.error("Error shutting down thread", ex);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public abstract void shutdown() throws Exception;
}
```

I'm instantiating KafkaProbeConsumer as the argument for a Thread and running it.
Here's the stack trace:

```
2024-01-08 12:43:09:130 INFO  KafkaProbeConsumer:32 - Kafka Consumer created
2024-01-08 12:43:09:132 INFO  KafkaConsumer:912 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-"probe-reader-id"-1, groupId="probe-reader-id"] Subscribed to topic(s): kafka-svil-probe
2024-01-08 12:43:09:301 INFO  NetworkClient:977 - [Producer clientId=producer-my-transaction-id, transactionalId=my-transaction-id] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-01-08 12:43:09:305 INFO  NetworkClient:344 - [Producer clientId=producer-my-transaction-id, transactionalId=my-transaction-id] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 0 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 175ms, elapsed time since send: 175ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-01-08 12:43:09:306 WARN  NetworkClient:1105 - [Producer clientId=producer-my-transaction-id, transactionalId=my-transaction-id] Bootstrap <address>:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-01-08 12:43:09:307 INFO  NetworkClient:977 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-"probe-reader-id"-1, groupId="probe-reader-id"] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-01-08 12:43:09:307 INFO  NetworkClient:344 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-"probe-reader-id"-1, groupId="probe-reader-id"] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 1 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 19ms, elapsed time since send: 19ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-01-08 12:43:09:307 WARN  NetworkClient:1105 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-"probe-reader-id"-1, groupId="probe-reader-id"] Bootstrap broker <address>:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-01-08 12:43:09:458 INFO  NetworkClient:977 - [Producer clientId=producer-my-transaction-id, transactionalId=my-transaction-id] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-01-08 12:43:09:459 INFO  NetworkClient:344 - [Producer clientId=producer-my-transaction-id, transactionalId=my-transaction-id] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 1 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 22ms, elapsed time since send: 22ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-01-08 12:43:09:459 WARN  NetworkClient:1105 - [Producer clientId=producer-my-transaction-id, transactionalId=my-transaction-id] Bootstrap broker <address>:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2024-01-08 12:43:09:459 INFO  NetworkClient:977 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-"probe-reader-id"-1, groupId="probe-reader-id"] Node -1 disconnected.
2024-01-08 12:43:09:459 INFO  NetworkClient:344 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-"probe-reader-id"-1, groupId="probe-reader-id"] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 2 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 22ms, elapsed time since send: 22ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2024-01-08 12:43:09:474 WARN  NetworkClient:1105 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-"probe-reader-id"-1, groupId="probe-reader-id"] Bootstrap broker <address>:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```